# c# 9 contextual keywords or,and,not

Tags: c#

Based on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns), C# 9 includes new "and", "or" and "not" keywords. I do not understand why, or when, one should use "or" instead of "||", "and" instead of "&&", etc.

What problem does the contextual keywords "or", "and", and "not" solve that the original conditionals ("||", "&&", etc.) didn't?

Comment: I mean, there are code examples *right there*. The code shows the use of `and` and `or`, to mean things that are different from what it would mean to use `&&` or `||` in those places. There are links to other parts of the proposal. What's unclear about it? Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation, especially not documentation that you already have.

Comment: I'm not sure why your question is getting downvoted, but based on some of these answers it appears that people don't understand the nature of the question. Perhaps if you added some specific examples and made it clear that you weren't mixing languages (e.g. using C# to generate dynamic SQL) it would help. I think the intent of the question is a really good one.

Comment: It is a language feature and it makes little or no sense asking why is it like it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
if (a == 1 || a == 2)
```

or

```
if (a == 1 or 2)
```

The 2nd version is shorter and, in theory, easier to parse as a human.

It's also easier to write

```
if (a is (>2 and <4) or (>5 and <7) )
```

Comment: yes I can, but why is it there? Why do we need to ways of doing `or`? what problem does this feature solve?

Comment: @gh9: not every feature solves a problem. Some things are just there to make code more readable. If you want to use that feature is up to you.

Comment: @gh9 You cannot make [logical patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) with the boolean `&&`, `||`, or `!` operators. You must use `and`, `or`, or `not` in these cases. As mentioned in Paurian's answer, this is to remove ambiguity when declaring complex cases.

Comment: This has little to do with human readability and more to do with the complexity of parsing tokens and interpreting their intent in the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely referring to C# 9's pattern matching. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements)

Using "and" and "or" is to ensure that binary operations are not ambiguous to the compiler.

This article contains more information:
https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/07/CSharp-And-Or-Not/

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing Neil's example and Paurian's linked article, let's say you have this:

```
bool? x = SomeFunction();
if (x == null || x == true) { SomeOtherFunction(); }
```

| x | Result |
| --- | --- |
| true | function called |
| false | function skipped |
| null | function called |

With the introduction of pattern matching, we don't have to say `x ==` twice. Instead we can say:

```
if (x is null or true) { SomeOtherFunction(); }
```

If we didn't have `is` and `or` as a context-sensitive keywords and used `==` and `||` instead, it would be ambiguous to the compiler, because this expression can mean something else in a pre-Patterns world.
That pre-Patterns expression is:

```
if (x == null || true) { SomeOtherFunction(); }
```

Which gives a different result for the case where x is `false`.

| x | Result |
| --- | --- |
| true | function called |
| false | function called |
| null | function called |

So to avoid this ambiguity, the language designers added separate keywords. See [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1350#issuecomment-369784194) on the GitHub thread for these keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It's just syntactic sugar for comparing values against constant expressions. When you need to compare a variable or property to one or more constant values, you can use these *Logical Patterns* to shorten your code and improve readability.

This is also useful when paired with `switch` expressions; as per the [documented example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns):

> ```cs
> static string Classify(double measurement) => measurement switch
> {
>     < -40.0 => "Too low",
>     >= -40.0 and < 0 => "Low",
>     >= 0 and < 10.0 => "Acceptable",
>     >= 10.0 and < 20.0 => "High",
>     >= 20.0 => "Too high",
>     double.NaN => "Unknown",
> };
> ```

Here, we can execute a case based on a range of numbers aided by Logical Expressions.

Since enum values are constant, we can also use this pattern like so:

```cs
enum E {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}
E e = E.A;

// Using logical expressions:
bool logical = e is E.A or E.B;

// V.S. the more wordy.
bool standard = e == E.A || e == E.B;
```